SDL2 unmet dependencies on Lubuntu 22.04
guys im getting this error when trying to install sdl2 or libsdl2-dev on lubuntu 22.04
Reading package lists... Done                              
Building dependency tree... Done                           
Reading state information... Done                          
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have                                                     
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable                                                    
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created                                                    
or been moved out of Incoming.                             
The following information may help to resolve the situation:                                                          
                                                           
The following packages have unmet dependencies:            
 libsdl2-2.0-0 : Depends: libdecor-0-0 (>= 0.2.2+git2403041401.4f2c03d~j~wayland1) but 0.1.0-3build1 is to be installed                                                          
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 

is this a known issue? i tried to install libdecor-0 0.2.2 manually but didnt worked

Don't forget by using 22.04 or the 2022-April release, you're using the fifth latest release (ie. 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 & 24.04 are newer)

ok i will try installing latest lts version
